# Fibonacci Search Algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods

Can someone show me an example of using this method for 'find the minimum of $$F(x) = x^2 - 6x + 2 \; \text{ on } [0,10] $$' ? [image]

I'm trying to follow the algorithm detailed above, but I don't understand it. How do they know at what $k$ to stop at? Why are they stopping at $k = 2$?

Comment: What have you tried out? An algorithm is a list of instructions. Follow step by step as described in the text. Btw they didn't stop at $k=2$ that was done only for demonstration of the method and they've given you the general formula for it. For the example, you also need to determine the accuracy (then number of steps) first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice in the algorithm they specified, they have:

$$\Delta = \dfrac{\lambda_{k-2}}{\lambda_k}(b-a)$$

where $\lambda$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number.

What happens when $k = 2$? We have:

$$\Delta = \dfrac{\lambda_{2-2}}{\lambda_2}(b-a) = \dfrac{\lambda_{0}}{\lambda_2}(b-a) = \dfrac{1}{2}(b-a)$$

Thus, we have gotten to the last $\Delta$ evaluation we can do, so we are left with doing one last function evaluation to choose our last range which contains the minimum value of $f$ at $\hat x$.

The way they wrote this algorithm is a bit difficult to read and other authors use a different approach for the number of iterations.

I rewrote the algorithm to one that is easier to follow (I hope):

- Step 1: Choose $f(x), a, b$
- Step 2: Choose a desired accuracy $\epsilon$ and calculate the number of steps $n = \dfrac{b-a}{\epsilon}$
- Step 3: $k = n$
- Step 4: $\Delta = \dfrac{\lambda_{k-2}}{\lambda_k}(b-a)$
- Step 5: Set $ap = a + \Delta$ and $bp = b - \Delta$
- Step 6: If $f(ap) \ge f(bp)$, set $a = ap, b = b$, else set $a = a, b = bp$.
- Step 7: $k = k - 1$
- Step 8: If $k > 2$, repeat from Step 4 through Step 7.
- Step 9: Since $k = 2$, If $f(a) \ge f(b)$, set $ap = \dfrac{1}{2}(a+b) - \epsilon, a = ap$, else set $bp = \dfrac{1}{2}(a+b) + \epsilon, b = bp$
- Step 10: Print $(a, b)$
- Step 11: Set the minimum point as $\hat x = \dfrac{1}{2}(a + b)$

For the example you gave, you should find $\hat x = 3 ~\pm ~\epsilon$

**Update** Note that a better approach to calculating the number of iterations is to find $k$ such that:

$$\lambda_{k+1} < \dfrac{b-a}{\epsilon}$$

Set $n = k$.